# Can't install any module

Tags: python, download, installation

I wanted to download pyperclip module. I have folder with some files like "docs" and so. There is also setup.py. I double click, black window opens and closes. I have red many pages in the Internet where have been described how to set up mudules, but i can't do that. For example, look at screenshot. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B66Wx.png). It says "command is not inside or ouside".
Can anyone give me ditailed instraction of instaling modules?

Comment: That is not how you install a module. You can `pip install pyperclip` from the command line, you should not try to just run `setup.py`

Comment: like that? [link] (http://prntscr.com/hwgxr8)

Answer (score -1):

First you need to add python to path (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7) answer
Then you need to install pip and [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) to correctly install packages
And after try install your package

Comment: Should i download setuptools-38.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (md5) from Setuptools or setuptools-38.4.0.zip (md5)?

Comment: Add python folder and Scripts (!) folder to path:
 {path to your python folder}Python36-32\Scripts
After that you can use pip to install packages: pip install setuptools